# Planning a laravel application - MVC disaster

Tags: laravel-5, model-view-controller, eloquent

I am currently creating a small Laravel project. The goal should be.
Every User can have 1 or more projects. Every project has data that displayed in Datatables.

The Problem. The data for each projects are different in structure (e.g. Addresses, Questionnaire, ...)

I have now created a separate model / view / controller for each project. But I think it's not the right way. e.g. 100 users have 2 projects, then I need 200 model / views / controller ???

How could I do better?
Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Two models only, one for a `User` (identified by an id in your database table `users`), one for a `Project` (identified by an id in your database table `projects`). Then in your database there are 100 users and 2 projects. You might want to read a little more about MVC, or even start with the Laravel documentation

Comment: Thanks for your comment kerbholz,
I have a user and project table. Each of the 100 users have 2 projects (100*2=200). The 200 projects have data (every project data is different in structure) and have no relation with each other. Hope you understand what I mean.